# Replacing and adding text in text files in Python

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I need to convert .ass subtitles file into .xml file. So far I did it by hand, but I have to do more and more of it.

That's how process looks like:

Input .ass file:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:00:08.03,0:00:10.57,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor says something
Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.28,0:00:21.05,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor says something
etc.
```

Output .xml file:

```
<p begin="00:00:08.03" end="00:00:10.57">Actor says something</p>
<p begin="00:00:11.28" end="00:00:21.05">Actor says something</p>
etc.
```

I dodn't know how to solve this task.

Comment: I think you can use the `csv`
 module to parse the input (provided you remove the "Dialogue" thing at the beginning), and then use an xml emitter to get your output (`xml.dom.minidom` should do the trick).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: You don't even need to remove the "Dialogue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should extract the relevant information from your source file. As the data is `,`-seperated, you can use the python csv module or do a simple `split(',')`.

This is an example method of how it could look like:

```
def extract(source):
    for line in iter(source):
        _, start, end, _, _, _, _, _, _, text = line.strip().split(',', 9)
        yield start, end, text
```

The next step if to convert your extracted data to the desired xml format. A function that plays well with the data from the first method could look like this (using simple string formatting):

```
xml = '<p begin="{start}" end="{end}">{text}</p>'
def to_xml(start, end, text):
    return xml.format(start=start, end=end, text=text)
```

Finally, opening the files and use the methods to write your output:

```
with open('input.ass') as infile, open('output.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    for start, end, text in extract(infile):
        outfile.write(to_xml(start, end, text) + '\n')
```

While you could of course make this smaller (less LOC), it is a readable approach IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
>>> subs = """Dialogue: 0,0:00:08.03,0:00:10.57,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor s
ays something, then some more
... Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.28,0:00:21.05,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor says someth
ing"""
>>> for line in subs.split("\n"):
...     print('<p begin="{0[1]}" end="{0[2]}">{0[9]}</p>'.format(
...            line.split(",", 9))) # Split no more than 9 times
...
<p begin="0:00:08.03" end="0:00:10.57">Actor says something, then some more</p>
<p begin="0:00:11.28" end="0:00:21.05">Actor says something</p>
```

Comment: this is not will be parsed because you did't add `root` element.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: Of course, but his sample output didn't either, so I assumed he would wrap it in a root element himself. After all, that's trivial.

Comment: thank you. i thought that topic starter did't know about xml validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
src = [
'Dialogue: 0,0:00:08.03,0:00:10.57,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor says something',
'Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.28,0:00:21.05,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Actor says something',
]
tpl = '<p begin="0%s" end="0%s">%s</p>'
for i in src:
    fields = i.split(',')
    start, end, txt = fields[1], fields[2], fields[-1]
    print tpl % (start, end, txt)
```

Comment: What if the subtitle itself contains a comma?